# Auto increment number column based on another 2 columns in the table

Tags: sql-server

In MS-SQL server I have a table named (Invoices) includes 4 columns

```
[InvoiceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL (Primary Key)
[OrgID] [int] NULL
[CompanyID] [int] NULL
[InvoiceNo] [int] NULL
```

In this table each organization (OrgID column) and subsidiary (CompanyID column) must have its sequence of InvoiceNo. something like following:

```
InvoiceID            OrgID           CompanyID       InvoiceNo
-------------------- --------------- --------------- -----------
1                    1               101             1
2                    1               101             2
3                    1               101             3
4                    2               201             1
5                    2               201             2
6                    2               201             3
7                    2               202             1
8                    2               202             2
9                    2               202             3
```

I tried many ideas to make InvoiceNo column increases by one based on OrgID and CompanyID when new row is inserted:

1. use `select row_number() over(partition by OrgID, CompanyID order
   by ID) + 1` in a trigger.
2. use above select directly as a value of InvoiceNo column in
   insert statement or put it in a function and call it in insert.
3. Create a view and inner join with insert.

The system used heavily by tens of users, When two different users in same organization and company insert an invoice, the InvoiceNo duplicates and two different invoices take the same number because when select statement executed as a part of insert stored procedure, the row still doesn't committed.

I created a Non Clustered Index to avoid duplication but it throw an exception when above scenario occurred. So it hide the problem but doesn't fix it.

I read about computed columns and it is a great solution for my problem but is it possible to partition by columns in computed column formula? If not, What do you suggest to fix InvoiceNo duplication?

Please note that many tables in the database (around 50 tables) have OrgID and CompanyID columns and all of them must have OrgID, CompanyID based sequence.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a window function (like ROW_NUMBER) in a computed column, but there's a great workaround. Create a scalar-valued function with the window function inside it, and then you can use the scalar function in the computed column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetInvoiceNo(@InvoiceID INT)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @InvoiceNo INT
    ;WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT InvoiceID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrgID, CompanyID ORDER BY InvoiceID) rn
        FROM dbo.Invoices
    )
    SELECT @InvoiceNo = rn
    FROM cte
    WHERE cte.InvoiceID = @InvoiceID

    RETURN @InvoiceNo
END
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Invoices ADD InvoiceNo AS dbo.fnGetInvoiceNo(InvoiceID)
GO
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Invoices
```

Returns:

```
InvoiceID   OrgID   CompanyID   InvoiceNo
1           1       101         1
2           1       101         2
3           1       101         3
4           2       201         1
5           2       201         2
6           2       201         3
7           2       202         1
8           2       202         2
9           2       202         3
```

Comment: Great, Thank you. How to retrieve computed column value in insert stored procedure? I use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to retrieve InvoiceID value, What the way of retrieving InvoiceNo?